# Adt eclipse phantom error

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I was developing a simple app and eclipse says that i cannot run the app because there are errors. I try to find that error, but everything is perfect! Its a simple app(a counter)...
Please Help!

Print Screens:
[I cannot post images because of my low reputation(this is my third question)]
EDIT: 
There is nothing wrong and it does not report any bug. When i click "RUN" it just says "Your project contain error(s), Please fix them before running your application".

Comment: open the `Error Log` in eclipse to find what the errors were

Comment: See **Problems** tab. Sometimes, clean build helps.

Comment: see the `console message` what it says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to make a full clean of your project.

1. Right click your project name. Android Tools > Fix Project Properties. If you have multiple Library Projects linked to this project, follow the same step with them first.
2. Hit the top menu Project > Clean. Select the radio button Clean all projects and hit OK.

You should leave Eclipse doing its job (depending on the amount of projects and files, it may take a while). If this doesn't work, follow the same process, but as a third step, close Eclipse and restart it right after you hit the OK button. Eclipse is powerful, but a silly IDE sometimes.

If the problem is there after restarting, and you have some libraries attached, check inside the Project build paths (right click the project name, Project Properties > Java Build Path) have the proper JARs, only once, and before any Android Library